# How can I persist a session when I redirect to another website in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session-variables

A website A makes a post to a website B, B says "OK" and store an object into a session. A read the "OK" and then redirect the user to B. At that moment, the session object is null. 
Both websites are in the same domain.
I need to persist the object session when I make the redirect

Comment: You can't depend on the session as they aren't the same. Store whatever you need in the database, and then grab it back out in the other site.

Comment: You can configure asp.net to store session state in the database.

Comment: Are you talking about preventing the session from timing out? Simply doing a redirect does not clear session.

Comment: @RobertMoskal can I test that locally? I mean if I want to store the session state on IIS Express?

Comment: Sure, you set up the session store inside your config file: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN "ASP.NET session state enables you to store and retrieve values for a user as the user navigates ASP.NET pages in a Web application."

You are talking about persisting values from one Web application to another, session state is not designed for that.

You will need to persist values to a store that is available to both applications such as ASP.Net cache or a database.

Although, as is pointed out above, session state can be configured to persist to a database, since IIS is managing that database via the session objects, it still prevents access of the session data cross application.

Comment: so there is a way to store a session state? and retrieve the session for a particular user?

Comment: can I do it locally with IISExpress?

Comment: No. If you need to persist user related data between applications, you will need to choose another data store to use. Session will not work for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of stars that have to align for this to work:

1. The two sites must be on the same domain or subdomains of that domain. If you're dealing with two completely different domain names, you're flat out of luck.
2. Both sites must have their session mode be a StateServer that they both can access or SQL Server. If SQL Server, you must persist the session in a database that can be accessed by both sites.
3. You'll need to configure the machine key for each site to be the same. See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755177%28v=ws.10%29.aspx